# Does Islam require that its followers enforce Islamic Government ruled by Sharia?

Tags: sharia, islamic-government

I would like to learn more about any Islamic precepts which mandate that Muslims organize their society as an Islamic state governed by the Sharia.  Are there such precepts and where are they (Quran/Hadith)?  Establishment and maintenance of such government has been a central theme in many Muslim societies for centuries.  What mandates that a group of Muslims organize an Islamic government?  Are Muslims still required to strive for such government and laws even when minority in the country of residence?

Comment: Sunni and Shiites have different views on the question of government and leadership. As for the Shiite view you may want to start by these two wiki entries on the [theory of Guardianship of the Islamic Jurists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardianship_of_the_Islamic_Jurists) as first [formulated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_Government:_Governance_of_the_Jurist) by Ruhollah Khomeini the founder of Islamic Republic of Iran. As for the Sunni theories, I hope one of the Sunni brothers on the site can guide you.

Answer (score 0):

Lets look it in this way. When you come of age it becomes mandatory to offer prayers. When you start possessing enough wealth, paying zakah becomes mandatory. When you marry only then the rules regarding married life become applicable to you. In short, when you qualify certain conditions only then the relevant directives become applicable to you. *You not NOT strive for qualification in order to become eligible for following a directive*

Similarly, when Muslims start ruling some land it becomes mandatory for them to implement shariah laws. Acquiring land, however, is not an Islamic directive. Let me emphasize: one cannot argue that because there are directives in Islam that have to implemented by a state therefore trying to acquire one is also a directive of Islam. No, it is just that when Muslims get rule of a land (e.g. democratically or as in the past some Muslims king conquers a land) then they should implement Shariah Laws.

Comment: So if Muslims live in a democratic state, should they vote for Shariah laws?

Comment: Yes and if majority votes positively then the law will be put into effect. In fact, that method can be used to choose from different interpretations of a particular law.

Answer (score -2):

Islam does not impose.  In a Muslim land there are people who are not Muslims so it is not ok to impose sharia law upon them.  Let the people choose the form of government that is fair to all.